# why this memory out of bound write not reported by kasan

Tags: linux-kernel, address-sanitizer

I'm learning kasan, and write a small kernel module to verify kasan

```c
static int __init test_init(void)
{
        char *a = kmalloc(10, GFP_KERNEL);
        a[20] = 0;
        return 0;
}
```

I build this module, and `insmod` on my arm device.

```sh
/tmp # tftp -g 192.168.3.100 -r test.ko
test.ko              100% |********************************| 19172  0:00:00 ETA
/tmp # insmod ./test.ko
```

Kasan report nothing.

Comment: What CONFIG flagds did you use and what command line parameters?

Comment: -O0 -g   -fsanitize=kernel-address -fasan-shadow-offset=0x5f000000   --param asan-globals=1   --param asan-instrumentation-with-call-threshold=0   --param asan-instrument-allocas=1   --param asan-stack=1

Comment: do i need some cflags when build external module ?

Comment: add `char *a = kmalloc(10, GFP_KERNEL); a[20] = 0;` to in tree module `lib/test_kasan_module.c` , kasan can report.

Comment: All code should be built with the ASAN flags

Comment: can make it more clear? how to set ASAN flags? @stark

Answer (score 0):

as `lib/test_kasan_module.c` suggest I should call `kasan_save_enable_multi_shot()`
to enable multi-shot mode. Otherwise, KASAN would only report the first detected bug

Answer (score 0):

My uneducated guess is that the slab is 24 bytes, since 10 byte allocations go into kmalloc-32. Since the read is still in the slab, KASAN should not trigger an OOB-read report as (I think) KASAN could not know the requested size of the allocation.